# If webbrowser navigates to a certain URL then do this? VB

Tags: vb.net, url, if-statement, checkbox, browser

I've looked everywhere for this! All I need to do is:

```
If the webbrowser's url = "http://www.example.com" then 
   CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked 
end if
```

thanks.

.... later on I found the answer:
I finally found the answer:

```
If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = "http://www.example.com" Then
        do something
End If
```

This must be in the webbrowser document completed sub:

```
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    End Sub
```

so all in all, the answer in full is:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted   

   If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = "http://www.example.com" Then
        do something
   End If

end sub
```

Comment: When you find the answer to your own question, post it as an asnwer rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event.

Check out the example given in the same page.

Comment: this doesn't say anything about checking the URL

Comment: The event handler is passed an object of [WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserdocumentcompletedeventargs.aspx)  that has a sole property that is the Url !!